# Angular unit test function when constructor needs many arguments

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I want to unit test functions in a component.
This component constructor needs four arguments.
I tried to set just arguments like (new AClass, new BClass, new CClass, new DClass), but then some of the classes need arguments by theme self. 
So it is getting complicate and a long way.

**How to deal with it?**

Thanks for support,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Angular testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing) to see how you can test a component, even one with multiple arguments in it's constructor.

Basically you will configure a testing module, provide everything your component will need to be instantiated and then when you launch your tests, Angular will inject what's needed itself the same way it happens when you are running your app.

Hope that helps

Comment: I've been looking up the tutorial.
But I could not find the ansere to my question.

Comment: It's not a tutorial but a testing guide, and the "Component with a dependency" section describes exactly what you're trying to do ...

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can call the method straight on the component object

```html
_myComponent = _fixture.componentInstance;
```

looks like that:

```html
        it('test function getLanguageImagePath()', () => {
            const result = _myComponent.getLanguageImagePath('en');
            expect(result).toEqual('assets/images/en_GB.svg');
        });
```

It works well.